# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. MVC EF 4.1 Codefirst getting started

Tags: sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I checked here and the internet with no answer. How do I get this to work  ?  I am using discountasp.net SQL so is it a setting on thier side to make it work  ?

Comment: How did you finally solve this @punkouter? I have the same issue, I tried supplying my own connection and creating my own data base, doesn't solve it

Comment: I am currently having a related problem at the moment (just got back into this) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810586/mvc-code-first-connection-string-i-changed-it-how-do-i-reinitialize-the-databa

Answer (score 5):

The following blog post explains this well.  If you haven't specified a connection string in your web.config than EF CodeFirst will attempt to create a DB on your local instance of SQLExpress.  Otherwise you can set the intent by assigning to a named connnection string via the public constructor of your entities context inheriting from the base constructor.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx

```
    public class UnicornsContext : DbContext
    {
        public UnicornsContext()
           : base("UnicornsCEDatabase")
        {
        }
    }
```

Either way you'll need to ensure that your account has appropriate access to the SQL(Express) server to create a new database.

Comment: Even better calling `: base("name=UnicornsCEDatabase")` which throws an Exception when the specified ConnectionString was not found.

Answer (score 1):

User in connection string used to access database has no create database right, so the exception is thrown. Try changing user or giving him access rights.

Comment: In code first you don't *have* to specify a connection string and it will try to create the database based on a set of conventions, it's unclear given what the OP has told us whether or not he has supplied one.

Comment: I did't say that HE specified connection string. Database connection needs user anyways, doesn't it?

Comment: yes.. I needed to give the connection string the name of the context name and that fixed that but now I have a more confusion problem

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var db = new DMContext())
            {
                return View(db.DmHighScores.ToList());
            }
          //  return View();
        }

Comment: {"Invalid object name 'dbo.DMHighScores'."}    but its clearly there.. No idea what to do now..

Comment: No it is not there definitely. Maybe you changed connection string to other database mistakely, where you don't have that object. Sql server is not making mistakes in finding objects

Comment: On a limb here: Could it be that the object names are case-sensitive? Your error mentions "DMHighScores", but your code mentions "DmHighScores"...