# MVC Code First Connection String. I changed it. How do I reinitialize the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I mean I was using a .SDF file but then had issues getting that to work with my host. So then I went back to the SQL DB I already have but I noticed that when I go to the default MVC 4 index page it is looking for that entity that I already created when I used the original DB.. but this table does not exist with the new SQL DB I switched to..

I already verified that is is pointing to the new DB buy setting the connection string in the constructer.

How do I tell the code to 'RE CREATE THE TABLE' before trying to use it ?

Comment: When I do a script table as... In MSSQL than it uses master to create it. Maybe you can do the same thing in code

Comment: Well I found a ugly work around.. Just script the table from where it put the old table to the DB I want the new table.. but the better solution would be to make it aware it needs to re create the tables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for something like Entity Framework Migrations: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx